# PG&E's Groundline distribution system

Tags: electrical, outdoor, conduit, cables, underground

The other day I saw an article reporting how PG&E is planning to use "tech" to achieve its target to underground 10,000 miles.

They demo'ed something called a "Groundline distribution system".
I found a patent here titled  ["Ground level primary electric distribution system" (US11621549B2)](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11621549B2)

Won't they have to change the NEC to make this code compliant?

> The utility also unveiled its new groundline distribution system,
> which entails undergrounding 10,000 miles of lines in its 44,000-mile
> system using ground level conduits, instead of spending more to dig
> deeper and tear up rock and the concrete and asphalt of streets.
>
> The program started last year with 180 miles of cable brought down
> from above, where contact with trees and animals can start fires. It’s
> on pace for 350 miles this year. PG&E officials said the process
> typically costs about $3.5 million per mile of cable going
> underground.
>
> The new method — which inserts the cable into a
> hard surface that typically can’t be cut open with everyday tools (and
> withstands being run over by semi-trucks without damage) will cost
> about $1.5 million to $2 million per mile and be done 2-3 times
> faster. The boxes can be put a few inches into the ground, but without
> the typical fuss of digging trenches.

[image: A cutaway model of PG&E’s groundline distribution system.2]

Comment: "What do folks here think about this?" -- it is off-topic

Comment: NEC is for homes.  The power companies have a different set of rules they need to follow(that is the idea anyway).  So no changes need to be done to the NEC.

Comment: It's cool but it's off topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a Home Improvement question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Won't they have to change the NEC to make this code compliant?

No, they would have to change [NESC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Electrical_Safety_Code).

Utilities running wires on their side of the customer electric meter are governed by [the NESC codebook](https://standards.ieee.org/products-programs/nesc/), not NEC.

Or in California, [GO95](https://ia.cpuc.ca.gov/gos/GO95/go_95_startup_page.html) or [GO128](https://ia.cpuc.ca.gov/gos/GO128/go_128_startup_page.html), which is written by the [California PUC](https://www.cpuc.ca.gov), but are probably largely cribbed from NESC.

Comment: But it doesn't matter anyway. As far as I know, there is no federal law mandating NEC/NESC. It is up to the states, which is why states can (and most do) have some exceptions to NEC and adopt new versions at different times. Similarly, a state can say "the law for this state is NESC *except* we add this requirement and subtract this requirement and modify..." And (right or wrong) a utility (public or private) can petition the state govt. (utility commission or whatever body sets the rules in that state) for variances. Just like a homeowner can ask for a zoning variance.

Comment: Indeed, there is an Authority Having Jurisdiction for the utility to decide what can be done.

Comment: @manassehkatz or the legislature simply delegates "the duty to promulgate regulations" to agency e.g. California PUC, and leaves the regulation writing to the agency. The agency can then go "We like NESC and "incorporate it by reference" into the regulations, or they can spin their own if they have the technical bandwidth to do so. **This also gives the regulatory agency the right to waive their own regulations on a case by case basis**. They can't waive laws.